# Cannot access the control id from a repeater's item template

Tags: asp.net

Friends,
 I have a linkbutton inside a repeater's item templete and i want to access the  link buttons text on the next page.I set the postbackurl to the next page.But when i use the page.PrevoiusPage.Findcontrol("lnkReport") on the destination page's code behind , I get a null value .These are the markups .Can anyone please help?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpmain" runat="Server">

<fieldset id="fsTrialAct"></fieldset>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptRepeater" runat="server">

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReport" 
       PostBackUrl="~/features/Reports/AdHocReportDetail.aspx"
             runat="server"><%#Eval("AdhocBurstingReportName")%>
</asp:LinkButton></p>

</asp:Repeater>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you can't do it, as there are multiple lnkReport LinkButtons being generated by Repeater on previous page.

Answer (score 0):

You use master pages thus your repeater reside in **Content Place Holder**. What you need to do is **find control** of the **Content Place Holder** first before you find the **repeater**.

Example:

```
Control placeHolder = PreviousPage.Controls[0].FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
TextBox SourceTextBox = (TextBox)placeHolder.FindControl("TextBox1");
if (SourceTextBox != null)
{
    Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
}
```

I assume in your case, instead of creating TextBox you should create repeater object and use **FindControl** again to find the link.